# Changing group from plugdev on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions

I have mounted an external disk on Debian (raspbian actually but it's roughly the same). The group for all directories and files on the drive are under the group plugdev.

This doesn't really suit what I want so I was going to change the group owner to something else.

Are there any knock on affects of doing this? I'm concerned I mess up the way that Debian interacts with the drive.

For example:

/media/hdd1 is my mount point which has the following

```
drwxr-sr-x 7 root root     4096 Feb 27 19:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Feb 27 20:17 ..
drwx------ 2 root root     4096 Feb 27 20:01 .fseventsd
drwxr-sr-x 5 root plugdev  4096 Feb 28 19:13 ftp_data
drwx------ 2 root plugdev 16384 Apr 13  2017 lost+found
```

I'd like to change the ftp_datas group to something else, but will this break it under the hood?

Comment: Depending on the filesystem that is on your external drive (FAT? ext3?), you can either supply options to `mount` that will set the default "faked" group to something else (`man mount`) for FAT or similar file systems, or you can change the "real" group with `chgrp` for ext3 or similar file systems.

Comment: I'm using ext4. I only really want to change the ftp_data folder's children. I'm happy to leave the /media/hdd1/ftp_data "top level" if you like as plugdev. Not sure if that will work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the filesystem you mounted is really `ext4`, that means it contains a numerical group id for every file and directory. On the system you have mounted it on, this numerical id maps to `plugdev`, which is a [Debian group](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups) that allows members to mount and umount removable devices through pmount. However, this numerical group id may have had a different meaning on whatever system created this filesystem.

So you can change the group ids, but be aware that when you take the harddisk somewhere else and mount id, the new group id may not make sense.

Changing the group is done with `chgrp`, and the recursive variant to change *all* files and directories under `ftp_data` is

```
chgrp -R name_of_new_group /media/hdd1/ftp_data
```

Not that both `ftp_data` and the root of this filesystem have the `s` group bit turned on, which means new groups will take the group id from the parent directory instead of using the group id of the user who creates the file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just a few queries on it. What would make you think that it wasn't ext4? Your first line makes me think that you think it's unlikely to be ext4, I was just wondering why that might be the case.

Comment: When I run df -T for the external drive I get "/dev/sda1      ext4". I have directories for each of the ftp users in the ftp_data directory. I want these directories (and their children directories and files) to be owned by that ftp user (who will not have a shell) and have a group of admin so that the ftp user can upload to that directory but an admin can have unrestricted rights over that users content. Not withstanding your comment about removing the drive, will this work and be secure?

Comment: Yes, it will work and be secure. You should consider a group `ftp` or `ftpadmin` instead of `admin`.

Comment: Thanks, for your help on this. I have so few admin users on my system (me only actually), that I think I should be able to just let adm control the ftp directories. On a larger system than I agree an ftpadmin group would be better. Thanks for you help again, it's been very helpful.